Python & Django web app - auto emails not sending - troubleshooting Cron
I have a webapp running on an ubunti vps.
Cron is scheduled to run a task evry sunday morning, however, I found it ran once and not again the next week. I have been reading about cron and how to troubleshoot but need help.
The lines below show my cron status - its running
sudo systemctl status cron
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-04-04 19:50:25 UTC; 2 days ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 605 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4647)
     Memory: 1016.0K
        CPU: 3.943s
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─605 /usr/sbin/cron -f -P

Apr 07 11:17:01 Software CRON[12453]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 07 12:00:01 Software CRON[12521]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Apr 07 12:00:01 Software CRON[12522]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q r>
Apr 07 12:00:01 Software CRON[12521]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 07 12:17:01 Software CRON[12528]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Apr 07 12:17:01 Software CRON[12529]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 07 12:17:01 Software CRON[12528]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 07 13:17:01 Software CRON[12626]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Apr 07 13:17:01 Software CRON[12627]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 07 13:17:01 Software CRON[12626]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
lines 1-21/21 (END)

cron -l shows
 0 5 * * Sun /root/venv/bin/python3 /root/manage.py send_due_email 

This script ran 1 time, but not again.
What should be looked at?
If the file can run, because it ran once before, what would cause it to not run the next week?

Show us the crontab entry.

This ran on the first Sunday after setting it up, but then not this morning:0 5 * * Sun /root/venv/bin/python3 /root/manage.py send_due_email

How exactly did you set up that crontab?  Did you set it up in some way that would not survive a system reboot?

I set it up by moving the file from the VPS to my my local pc, edit the file then upload it back to the server.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the file".

If you look at the cron schedule right now, does it still show the Sunday task?

for the file, I mean: I moved the root file from /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
contab -l shows: 0 5 * * Sun /root/venv/bin/python3 /root/manage.py send_due_email

What is the exact filename and the exact file permissions in  /var/spool/cron/crontabs/?

The file should be named your username, and I believe it should be owned by you, and have a group of crontab.  When you moved it, did you leave it owned by root?

I am not an experienced user, just trying to troubleshoot. I moved the file using Winscp, editted with Notepad++ and moved it back. I dont know how to change permissions, so I can say - I dont think i changed permissions.

I would recommend using celery workers/scheduler. You can setup the timers in the default Django administration. pretty handy. good luck with this issue, might be worth a look into though

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I editted the original post. Thank you for looking

If the permissions on the crontab file are wrong, crontab -l will (confusingly!) still show it, but it will not actually be executed.

After the cron ran the first week, did you change anything at all?

Also, how do you know for certain that the job did not run?

@John - Thank you - yes I did change something I thought would not break it. The app uses a gmail account to send data from the app once a week. The data did not send. I did change the gmail acct password and did not know when doing so, the app passkeys would be deleted each time you change the password - I re-added an app password and the email sent successfully.

So the cron job did run, it just didn't do what you expected, so you thought it didn't run at all.

Yes, no email so I figured it didn't run. I did find the log files and learned alot.
